# How to build ffmpeg with libwebp for android?

Tags: ffmpeg, webp, android-ffmpeg

I need use the ffmpeg (v2.8) to convert mp4 to webp, how to build ffmpeg with libwebp for android ?

I googled, but have little information to build ffmpeg with libwebp.

I try to add the configuration:

```
--enable-libwebp 
--enable-muxer=webp
--enable-encoder=libwebp
```

but i got the following compile error.

```
ERROR: libwebp not found using pkg-config

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

The config.log is:

```
check_pkg_config libwebp >= 0.2.0 webp/encode.h WebPGetEncoderVersion
false --exists --print-errors libwebp >= 0.2.0
ERROR: libwebp not found using pkg-config
```

Comment: `--enable-libwebp` is enough. There's sth wrong with your libwebp on that system. Make sure it is installed properly.

Comment: I'm on Mac Sierra, version: 10.12.1, how to install libwebp correctly ? Thanks @halfelf

Comment: There are many ways. The easiest may be `brew install webp`. The error message means `pkg-config` knows nothing about libwebp. `pkg-config --cflags --libs` should output sth like: `-I/usr/local/Cellar/webp/0.6.0/include -L/usr/local/Cellar/webp/0.6.0/lib -lwebp` after the installation.

Comment: Weird. I still got the compile error after i done the 'brew install webp'. @halfelf

Comment: I use the '$ pkg-config --list-all ', and i found 'libwebp' and 'libwebpmux' items. That's weird. @halfelf

Comment: Tested with ffmpeg-2.8.12 and nothing wrong myself. Check what `config.log` says.

Comment: I have updated the question description added the config.log information. @halfelf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as the following steps:

1. build libwebp by ndk-build
2. add *.a and *.h into a folder, such as libwebp-armv7a, under the project
3. link the webp without pkg-config

The way that @halfelf mentioned in comments is for PC build, not for Android mobile platform.

Comment: How to link webp without pkg-config?